# Include causes InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with this query in Entity Framework Core 1.1:

```
var leaves = _context.Proposal.OfType<ProposalLeave>()
                .Include(l => l.Creator).ThenInclude(e => e.User)
                .Include(l=>l.LeaveType) // this include causes the exception
                .Include(l => l.ProposalLeaveStatuses).ThenInclude(l => l.ProposalLeaveStatus)
                .ToList();
```

Include to LeaveType raise this error:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime'
>   to type 'System.Int32'.
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.SimpleNonNullableDependentKeyValueFactory.TryCreateFromBuffer(Valu fdc eBuffer valueBuffer, out TKey key)

My models:

```
public class Proposal
{
    [Key]
    public int ProposalId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatorId")]
    public Employee Creator { get; set; }
}

public class ProposalLeave : Proposal
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime LeaveStart { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime LeaveEnd { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ProposalLeaveTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProposalLeaveTypeId")]
    public virtual ProposalLeaveType LeaveType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProposalLeaveStatuses> ProposalLeaveStatuses { get; set; }
}

public class ProposalLeaveType
{
    [Key]
    public int LeaveTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProposalLeave> ProposalLeaves { get; set; }
}
```

A part of my DbContext:

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int>
{

    public DbSet<Proposal> Proposal { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProposalLeaveStatus> ProposalLeaveStatus { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProposalLeaveStatuses> ProposalLeaveStatuses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProposalLeaveType> ProposalLeaveType { get; set; }


    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        // proposal hierarchy
        modelBuilder.Entity<Proposal>()
            .HasDiscriminator<string>("proposal_type")
            .HasValue<Proposal>("proposal_base")
            .HasValue<ProposalCustom>("proposal_custom")
            .HasValue<ProposalLeave>("proposal_leave");

        // proposal statuses many to many
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProposalLeaveStatuses>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Proposal)
            .WithMany(p => p.ProposalLeaveStatuses)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.ProposalId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProposalLeaveStatuses>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.ProposalLeaveStatus)
            .WithMany(t => t.ProposalLeaveStatuses)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.ProposalLeaveStatusId);

        //Substantially, there are nothing about Proposal Leave Types, cause its relation one-to-many modeled using data annotations.
    }
}
```

I checked these models hundreds times and I don't know whats wrong. It's weird casuse I also have ProposalCustom:Proposal model contected with ProposalCustomType in the same way as ProposalLeave:Proposal to ProposalLeaveType and it works fine...

I discovered that if I add that line:

```
 var leaveTypes = _context.ProposalLeaveType.Include(plt => plt.ProposalLeaves).ToList();
```

before my query, it also works even with `.Include(l=>l.LeaveType)` without any exception...

I found a few bug issues on EF github referring to InvalidCastException, but all of them are marked as fixed in EF Core 1.1

**@Update**
Here you can download VS2015 project that reproduce that problem:
[Project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtgBak8wmGjhhAxEmMKDwO1laALG).
Setup:

1. Install .Net Core 1.1. sdk and runtime
2. Create empty database and replace connection string in appsettings.json
3. Run Update-Database in Package Manager Console
4. Run project.

Comment: Can't reproduce without the full model. What happens if you comment out the `.Include(l => l.ProposalLeaveStatuses).ThenInclude(l => l.ProposalLeaveStatus)` line?

Comment: @IvanStoev It still doesn't work. Only the removal of the line: `Include(l=>l.LeaveType)` fixes my problem. Thats why I skipped definitions of ProposalLeaveStatuses and ProposalLeaveStatus models in my question. In a moment I'll update my question by adding important parts of DbContext

Comment: I see. But looks like that affects somehow the process because w/o `.ThenInclude(e => e.User)` and the line mentioned in the first comment it doesn't happen, I mean, it works w/o errors.

Comment: @IvanStoev I added VS 2015 project that reproduce my problem. Could you confirm that you have the same bug and it might be problem with EF Core ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately all I can do is to confirm the obvious fact that the issue is caused by a EF Core bug.

I was able to trim down the repro to the following:

*Model:*

```
public class Proposal
{
    [Key]
    public int ProposalId { get; set; }

    [Required, Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string Substantiation { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}

public class ProposalCustom : Proposal
{
    [Required, StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ProposalTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProposalTypeId")]
    public virtual ProposalCustomType ProposalType { get; set; }
}

public class ProposalCustomType
{
    [Key]
    public int ProposalTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProposalCustom> ProposalCustoms { get; set; }
}

public class ProposalLeave : Proposal
{
    public DateTime LeaveStart { get; set; }

    public DateTime LeaveEnd { get; set; }

    public int ProposalLeaveTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProposalLeaveTypeId")]
    public virtual ProposalLeaveType LeaveType { get; set; }
}

public class ProposalLeaveType
{
    [Key]
    public int LeaveTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProposalLeave> ProposalLeaves { get; set; }
}
```

*DbContext:*

```
public DbSet<Proposal> Proposal { get; set; }
public DbSet<ProposalCustomType> ProposalCustomType { get; set; }
public DbSet<ProposalLeaveType> ProposalLeaveType { get; set; }
```

*Configuration:*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Proposal>()
    .HasDiscriminator<string>("proposal_type")
    .HasValue<Proposal>("proposal_base")
    .HasValue<ProposalCustom>("proposal_custom")
    .HasValue<ProposalLeave>("proposal_leave");
```

*Data:*

```
db.Proposal.Add(new ProposalLeave
{
    Substantiation = "S1",
    DateCreated = DateTime.Today,
    LeaveStart = DateTime.Today,
    LeaveEnd = DateTime.Today,
    LeaveType = new ProposalLeaveType { Name = "PLT1", Description = "PLT1" }
});
db.Proposal.Add(new ProposalCustom
{
    Substantiation = "S2",
    Name = "PC1",
    ProposalType = new ProposalCustomType { Name = "PCT1", Description = "PCT1" }
});
db.SaveChanges();
```

*Queries:*

```
var proposalCustoms = db.Proposal.OfType<ProposalCustom>()
    .Include(l => l.ProposalType)
    .ToList();

var proposalLeaves = db.Proposal.OfType<ProposalLeave>()
    .Include(l => l.LeaveType)
    .ToList();
```

Althought the `ProposalCustom` and `ProposalLeave` looks similar, the first query **always** works, the second doesn't (it does under **some** circumstances as you will see below).

Why I'm sure it is a bug. First, because there is nothing wrong with the query and/or the model/configuration. Looks like it's caused by a combination of a several factors, starting with TPH, number and type of the derived class properties and (hmm) the class names (alphabetical order?) of the derived entities.

For instance, if there is no `LeaveEnd` property, the second query works. And the funniest part (depending of the view of course) is that if you rename `ProposalCustom` class to `ProposalXCustom`, or `ProposalLeave` to `ProposalALeave`, in other words, make the problematic entity class name first in the alphabetical order (I know it sounds crazy), without any database structure / mapping change, the query works!

I would suggest you reporting it to the EF Core repository. `Substantiation` column and `Required` / `Column` attributes doesn't seem to affect the behavior. Also, note that the first query always works, and the order of execution doesn't matter.

Comment: The issue reported [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7312). Thanks for help.